# I deleted Android OS from my Karbonn device

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I have a smart phone (Karbonn A50,Android version 2.3.6) which was rooted earlier.

While accessing my files on the memory card, I came to know that I can access the system files and apps:think OS. I've selected all the files and tapped to delete them and got a warning not to delete. On repeated trying, I was able to delete them to some extent and the device got stuck.

Then I removed battery and switched it on. Nothings works. The phone gets stuck on boot logo (karbon smart) and if try to switch it off it doesn't, until I remove the battery.

If connect to PC, it notifies that something has been detected but no device is seen in my computer. I can't access factory reset either.

Please help me.

Comment: hmm :( please do help man

Answer (score 0):

You mean you deleted Files from /SYSTEM/ folder.

If yes then Bro you did a big mistake. Your device got corrupted.To recover  Download android ROM for your device from internet then go to download mode and flash it using ODIN .

1. You can download ROM from LINK: http://androidxda.com/download-karbonn-stock-rom-models
2. Download ODIN from http://odindownload.com/ (Requires PC)

Comment: I would NOT recommend downloading odin from that site. There are plenty of posts and etc on XDA saying that site packages viruses and malware with odin. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2712008&page=2 You can find plenty of legit links on XDA for odin.

Comment: hey can you please give in detail the process of getting download mode and flashing

thanx!

Comment: 1. You can goto download mode by press and hold volume down button home button and power button together! Then when you will see download screen leave keys and follow instruction.

Comment: 2. Connect usb cable to your phone and pc

Comment: 3. Run ODIN and select rom you downloaded for your deice from above link.

Comment: 4. Click Flash and wait. You phone will auto-reboot after complete.

Comment: 5. After your OS will load, disconnect usb cable and do setup.

Comment: 6. Done! Enjoy........ And hit the UP button of this answer.